# 400 Bad Request when URL ends with %

Tags: apache, .htaccess, internal-server-error

All the URLs ending with % is giving following error

"Bad Request,Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand."

I have redesigned my website and earlier as per my google analytics URLs ending with % was running.

I want to mention that I tried using same old htaccess but was not able to fix it. Other important change which I made was in hosting where I have pointed my server into a sub folder or the root.

Please help me in fixing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` is a reserved character and should not be used for anything except percent encoding.

If you really need to pass the character on your url, use `%25`

Comment: Please read my concern, I am aware of the point which you make but these pages use to open earlier somehow which is not opening now as they are indexed in google.

Comment: I understand that, but it really should NOT be used, because it's an unsafe character (acording to RFC-1738) and might not work in some browsers. http://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/

Comment: Maybe analytics was upgraded, maybe the browser was, maybe the webserver was... It really doesn't matter. It's not supposed to work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [400 Bad Request when URL ends with %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102444/400-bad-request-when-url-ends-with%)
(move your mouse over it and look at the URL, it's the URL of this page with a % added to it!)

The problem is probably that the % is used as an escape character for special signs like spaces or non latin characters, and the browser expects a code behind it.

Comment: I agree with your point but unfortunately when I check my google analyticy before the update it use to reselove to correct urls